# Number of non repeat divisible dividends (optimize)

Tags: algorithms, python

Please, am just learning some new algorithm and math concepts!

> Is there way on how I can improve my algorithm to get the optimal one in terms of computing time?

I mean compute the result for "hard" case, rather than getting the computer to do it

Given a range of non-zero dividend numbers $[A,B]$ such that $1\leq A , B \leq 10^{18}$, and a set of divisors $D = \{x: 1 \leq x \leq 50\}$, I want to find the total number of non-repeating dividends in [A,B] that can be divided by any number in set D.

**Example 1 (doesn't take too much time)**

The range of dividend numbers `[1,10]` and the divisors are `{2,3,4}`

- list of numbers divisible for divisor 2: `2,4,6,8,10`
- list of numbers divisible for divisor 3: `3,6,9`
- list of numbers divisible for divisor 4: `4,8`

So the total number of non-repeat divisible dividends in `[1,10] = 7`

**Example 2 (takes a lot of time)**

```
[A,B] = [79031836253224256, 403892407826392155]
D = {44, 46, 50, 8, 35,41,6,18, 24, 23, 7, 45, 39, 46, 4, 35, 34}
Output: 161802330522861274
```

**1st version of the algorithm in Python**

```
def solution(A,B,D):                                                                                                                                                                         
    a = set()                                                                                                      
    for i in range(A,B+1):                                                                                         
            for j in D:                                                                                            
                    if i%j == 0:                                                                                   
                            a.add(i)                                                                               
    # return the count of a                                                                                        
    return len(a)   

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                             
        print(solution(1,10,[2,3,4]))
```

Comment: what tags do you want me to put there?

Comment: I would have put only `algorithms` and `python`.

Comment: Explain how you got the result in Exampele $2$

Comment: Not a complete solution , but an approach : Take the product of the numbers in $D$ and determine the set of the prime divisors of this product. Denote its product $P$. Then, every range $[k,k+P-1]$ contains $\phi(P)$ numbers that are not divisible by any number in $D$. $\phi(P)$ is the totient-function and $k$ any positive integer. Maybe this helps.

Comment: My approach assumes that $D$ does not contain $1$, in this case the problem is trivial.

Comment: Please, once the prime divisors founded I must denote their product as P? Also what k exactly is? Can you please give an example based on this range [1,10] and D = {2,3,4}